# How to fix cannot read serial.find("OK") from esp8266 response

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, arduino-esp8266

I'm try to connect my ESP8266 to wifi router using `AT+CWJAP` but I have a problem cannot read esp8266 response to my arduino.

When I try to send `AT` to esp from arduino code it can't read `OK` Response from esp8266 `Serial.find("OK")` not working. I change the baud rate into 115200 it didn't work too

This is serial capture:

```
> 14:04:45.882 -> AT 
> 14:04:51.868 -> NOT OK! 
> 14:04:51.901 -> AT+CIPSTART="TCP","184.106.153.149",80 
> 14:04:54.899 -> AT+CIPSEND=55
> 14:04:55.873 -> AT+CIPCLOSE
```

This is the arduino code:

```
void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600); //or use default 115200.
      Serial.println("AT");
      delay(5000);
      if(Serial.find("OK")){
        connectWiFi();
      }
      else{
        Serial.println("NOT OK!");
      }
    }
```

It should run `ConnectWiFi()` Function but the output is "NOT OK!"

Comment: So what data *does* the Arduino receive from the ESP?

Comment: "OK" response from esp

Comment: @ChristianMahardhika, Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: my device was broken so I change it then it works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your baudrate is [incorrect](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/AT_Description). It should be `115200`.

Comment: Or whichever baudrate the user set the ESP up to use.

Comment: I have tried 115200 but it still cannot read. Also when I check with serial.read() the result is -1 (int)

Comment: my device was broken so I change it then it works :D